# Difference between "why" and "what for"?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

What is the difference between "why" and "what for"? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that "What for?" is informal/conversational.

## "What Purposeful Reason?"

**"What for"** denotes a purposeful reason, while "Why?" can be used for causes, reasons, or explanations.

- **Statement 1: "I am going to work now."**
- **Why? (Explanation):**  "Because it's time for me to leave."
- **Why? OR What for? (Purpose):** "To make money."

  ---
- **Statement 2: "Things fall."**
- **Why (explanation):**  "Because of gravity..."
- **Why (Purpose):** "Because of gravity." / "No, I mean, why is it like that?  Why is there gravity?" / "Who knows? That's just the way it is. God? Quantum Multiverse? That may not be answerable."
- **What for (purpose only!):** "Who knows? God? Quantum Multiverse? That may not be answerable."

  ---
- **Statement 3: "I exist."**
- **Why (Explanation/Cause)**: "Because your parents had sex, your mother got pregnant, and you were born."
- **Why OR What for? (Purpose)**: "In order to propagate the species." **OR** "For God's mysterious reason." **OR** "Nobody knows." **OR** "There is no purpose; it's a quantum multiverse."

Variations can be created by sentences like "**What** is $NounPhrase$ **for**?" For example, if one is in a new car with a salesman, one can ask "**What** is that button **for**?" In this case, the question is asking for the functional purpose of the button.  Also, "What is math good for?" is asking for suitability for a purpose.

---

## "What for!?" -- Emphasis / Surprise / Suspicion

"What for" can lend itself to more emotion than a simple "Why", adding surprise, suspicion, or just more emphasis. In this case, "what for" can be asking for an explanation just like "why":

- **Statement 4: "I am going to work now."**
- **What for!? You just got home! (Surprise/Explanation):** / "Because I left my wallet there."

The emotion behind "What for?" can also be suspicion or interrogation. There can be a bit of eye squinting or head tilting:

**"Can I ask you your name?"**
**"Ummm.  What for?"**  (Suspicion)
[image]

---

## "For what?" -- Identifying ambiguity.

**"What for"** can also be used to mean **"For what?"** in order to identify an ambiguous reference. The emphasis is on replacing the "what" with the named item rather than replacing the "for" with the named reason:

1. "I'm looking for something." / **"For what?"** / "For my glasses."
2. "I'm looking for something." / **"What for?"** / "My glasses." (Same as "For what")
3. "**What** are you looking **for**?" / "My glasses."

Here's another one:

- "I need some help." / "**What for?**" / "To reach that top shelf." / "Ok, **what for**?" / "That coffee mug."

Both **"what for"** questions could be asking for **purposeful reason**. For example, in the 2nd case, the reason could have been to clean the shelf. But the ***answer*** given in the 2nd case was an ***identification*** of the object desired.

Also, "**What** am I responsible **for**?" is asking for identification of responsibilities. It is like "**For what** am I responsible?", but the [fronted what](https://www.google.com/search?q=wh+fronting+grammar+OR+linguistics) sounds more natural.

Answer (score 7):

**Why** asks about a *reason*, **what for** about a *purpose*.

The distinction is not always clear, but a reason is the *cause* of something, and a purpose is the *result* of something.

> Why are you wet? Because it is raining.

It would not make much sense to assume someone intended to get or be wet for a specific purpose, so I assume that something *caused* the person to be wet. Hence, I ask *why*.

> [War, what is it good for?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX7V6FAoTLc)

The question asked here is not "what causes war to be a good thing?", but "what purpose does war serve?".

Comment: *"I'm going to get wet."* *"What for?"* *"Because I think it'll help rehydrate my dry skin."*